# How to secure a web service for mobile app with no auth

Tags: java, android, ios, web-services, mobile

I need to provide a web api for my mobile app to collect location data. The problem is that mobile app users do not have to login and there is no login for mobile app at all. Taking into consideration this fact how can I secure my web service from random guy making an HTTP call ?

Comment: In my opinion, you can use an access_token or special http header

Comment: add a source key or use an identifier thats known only to the app.  bit pack your data in a way that only you can pull apart.  the solutions are never ending.

Comment: @Burrito 
I thought about this, but this will not prevent someone to decompile apk and get that key.